# UIVisualEffect view edge-to-edge do not line up

Tags: ios, uikit, uivisualeffectview

I want to have a table view with custom cells in it, and with a consistent blurring that moves with the content when scrolling.  The easy solution was to have the custom cells contain a UIVisualEffectView.

Unfortunately when I put UIVisualEffectViews next to each other, the edges are noticeable and the blurs do not line up.  Does anyone know of a way to fix this so that edge-to-edge UIVisualEffectViews do not show a "seam"?

[image: example]

Comment: have you solved this ? I have the same problem

Comment: @David I was not able to solve this, instead I placed a single large UIVisualEffectView on a separate scroll view overlapping the table, and set up a 1:1 content size and offset with the table view.